# What is the dimension of the vector space $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/(2xy-y^2,x^2-2xy)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to compute the delta invariant of a certain plane curve singularity. It's led me to consider the vector space
$$\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]/(2xy-y^2,x^2-2xy)$$

Let $I := (2xy-y^2,x^2-2xy)$.

Then certainly we have the inclusions

$$(x,y)^2\subset I \subset (x,I)\subset (x,y)\subset (1)$$

Clearly the final inclusion has a dimension 1 quotient. Now $(x,y)/(x,y)^2$ is 2-dimensional, since $\mathbb{C}[[x,y]]$ is a regular local ring of dimension 2. Thus the quotients in the first three inclusions must give dimensions that partition 2.

Clearly $x\notin I$, so $I\subsetneq (x,I)$.

Moreover, $(x,I) = (x,y^2)$, so $y\notin (x,I)$, so $(x,I)\subsetneq (x,y)$. Since $(x,y)/(x,y)^2$ is 2-dimensional, this means we must have $\dim(x,I)/I = \dim(x,y)/(x,I) = 1$, but that would force $I = (x,y)^2 = (x^2,xy,y^2)$, which seems absurd to me. Could this be true?

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: Just FYI: one can show that $I = (y^3, x^2 - y^2, 2xy - y^2)$. (This is a Gröbner basis for $I$.)

Answer (score 1):

You write, "certainly we have the inclusions $(x,y)^2 \subset I \subset (xI) \subset (x,y) \subset (1).$" The first of these inclusions is not valid; indeed clearly $I \subset (x,y)^2$, so the other containment would force equality. Of course these ideals cannot be equal; $I$ is two-generated while $(x,y)^2$ has minimal number of generators equal to $3$.